# Content Not Loading Via SSL

Tags: php, html, ssl

I have a banner in which the HTML is loaded into my file via:

```
<?php require("banner.php"); ?>
```

When I attempt to load my page via SSL (https://vantagewebservices.com/) the banner does not load. Chrome and FF are warning me that some of my scripts are not being loaded over SSL. However, the links in the HTML are all dynamic in the way that they are link via the root of my website and not by the domain. The banner.html file that is loaded into my index page can be found here: vantagewebservices.com/banner.html. If you can help me resolve this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.` it tells you what. theres many of these. At least for Chrome it won't load some HTTP content when visiting a HTTPS site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your scripts are not loading via `https`, change the following lines to be protocol relative as mentioned by @Ennui below.

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The main problem is that JQuery was not loading which your banner is dependent on.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer/solution.

Comment: @Ennui, there you go now its a solution

Comment: Thank you so much. The first thing I should of checked, and I totally forgot to do so. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey +1'd :) see that wasn't hard!  I would have mentioned [protocol relative urls](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) though instead.

Comment: @wesslayneb do bear in mind that if you are developing locally, protocal relative urls will generally be interpreted as `file://` rather than `http://` or `https://` (as explained in the Paul Irish blog post I linked in my previous comment)

Comment: and IE6 has issues with protocol relative urls as mentioned in the article @Ennul mentioned